# IBM db2Command SQL SELECT * FROM IN @namedParameter

Tags: c#, db2

When using the C# code below to construct a DB2 SQL query the result set only has one row.  If I manually construct the "IN" predicate inside the cmdTxt string using string.Join(",", ids) then all of the expected rows are returned.  How can I return all of the expected rows using the db2Parameter object instead of building the query as a long string to be sent to the server?

```
public object[] GetResults(int[] ids)
    {
        var cmdTxt = "SELECT DISTINCT ID,COL2,COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ( @ids ) ";
        var db2Command = _DB2Connection.CreateCommand();
        db2Command.CommandText = cmdTxt;

        var db2Parameter = db2Command.CreateParameter();
        db2Parameter.ArrayLength = ids.Length;
        db2Parameter.DB2Type = DB2Type.DynArray;
        db2Parameter.ParameterName = "@ids";
        db2Parameter.Value = ids;
        db2Command.Parameters.Add(db2Parameter);

        var results = ExecuteQuery(db2Command);

        return results.ToArray();
    }


    private object[] ExecuteQuery(DB2Command db2Command)
    {
        _DB2Connection.Open();
        var resultList = new ArrayList();
        var results = db2Command.ExecuteReader();
        while (results.Read())
        {
            var values = new object[results.FieldCount];
            results.GetValues(values);
            resultList.Add(values);
        }
        results.Close();
        _DB2Connection.Close();
        return resultList.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `ids.Count()`? `ids.First()`? `ids.Last()`? If you put a breakpoint on `resultList.Add(values);` how many times does it get hit?

Comment: Does it work if you use `UNNEST`? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0055064.html

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `ArrayList` rather than `List<object>`?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: @mjwills ids.Length == 6 and expected results is 5 (included one bad Id to test query accuracy).  If I break at resultList.Add(values) the break point is only hit once.

Comment: @Charles  Please excuse my ignorance as I'm VERY new to IBM DB2 development, but I believe the platform name is AS400.  The IBM.Data.DB2.dll version number is 10.1.4.4.

Comment: @mjwills I haven't tried UNNEST, but I'm not sure that's relevant here.  I'm not trying to query an array variable.  I'm trying to pass a parameterized string as my sql command where the parameter is an array of IDs.

Comment: What version of IBM i OS?  (It hasn't been called an AS/400 for 20 years).  SQL arrays were added a few years back in v7.1.  But I don't know if they'd work like you're trying to use them from C#

Comment: @Charles Not sure...we definitely still call our environment "AS/400". Speaking with another dev on my team, I think we may just stick using string.join() to filter on the Id column.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send in an array as a parameter. You would have to do something to build out a list of parameters, one for each of your values.

e.g.: `SELECT DISTINCT ID,COL2,COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ( @id1, @id2, ... @idN )`

And then add the values to your parameter collection:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id1", DB2Type.Integer).Value = your_val;
```

---

Additionally, there are a few things I would do to improve your code:

1. Use [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around your DB2 objects. This will automatically dispose of the objects correctly when they go out of scope. If you don't do this, eventually you will run into errors. This should be done on `DB2Connection`, `DB2Command`, `DB2Transaction`, and `DB2Reader` objects especially.
2. I would recommend that you wrap queries in a transaction object, even for selects. With DB2 (and my experience is with z/OS mainframe, here... it might be different for AS/400), it writes one "accounting" record (basically the work that DB2 did) for each transaction. If you don't have an explicit transaction, DB2 will create one for you, and automatically commit after every statement, which adds up to a lot of backend records that could be combined.
3. My personal opinion would also be to create a .NET `class` to hold the data that you are getting back from the database. That would make it easier to work with using IntelliSense, among other things (because you would be able to auto-complete the property name, and .NET would know the type of the object). Right now, with the array of objects, if your column order or data type changes, it may be difficult to find/debug those usages throughout your code.

I've included a version of your code that I re-wrote that has some of these changes in it:

```
public List<ReturnClass> GetResults(int[] ids)
    {
        using (var conn = new DB2Connection())
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trans;

                var parms = new List<string>();
                var idCount = 0;
                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    var parm = "@id" + idCount++;
                    parms.Add(parm);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm, DB2Type.Integer).Value = id;
                }
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT ID,COL2,COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ( " + string.Join(",", parms) + " ) ";

                var resultList = new List<ReturnClass>();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var values = new ReturnClass();
                        values.Id = (int)reader["ID"];
                        values.Col1 = reader["COL1"].ToString();
                        values.Col2 = reader["COL2"].ToString();
                        resultList.Add(values);
                    }
                }
                return resultList;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReturnClass
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Col1;
        public string Col2;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing from:

```
db2Parameter.DB2Type = DB2Type.DynArray;
```

to:

```
db2Parameter.DB2Type = DB2Type.Integer;
```

This is based on the example given [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/r0055333.html)

Comment: Changing DB2Type to "Integer" still results in just one item returned from the database.